# Ownership of external drives

Tags: ssd, external-hdd

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a older hp laptop (intel core i7 with AMD Radeon Topaz - but its using the intel graphics as Topaz does not appear to be supported in 22.04)

I have two external USB drives both formatted using the same device.

I can read write delete on the external HDD (WD Elements SE Portable) however on the external SSD (sandisk portable SSD) I have to use the <sudo chown -R> command in terminal in order to be able to read write delete..

What is the reason for this behavior.

I use both the external disks to transfer video files from two old Topfield PVR's and they are both formatted in ext2.  The drive name details are from the data written on the outside of the device case. The SanDisk is model number SDSSDE30-480G and the WD Essential has part number WDBEPK0010BBK-0B.  I have used search to find the folders suggested but none seem to have any mention of the external drives. Where are they located?

Using GParted I note that the WD drive does not show a mount point whereas the SanDisk drive does.  The WD drive is the one I need to run the sudo chown -R command for.  Oops the WD drive was not mounted they both now show the same mount point. I usually just plug them in and click on the icon in the dock. Do I need to need to right click and mount when I plug them in?

Just tried copying from SSD to laptop after mounting and the error message I get when attempting copy from the SSD drive is:
Error while copying "filename"
There was an error copying the file into "home/usr/....."
Error opening file "mountpoint "Disklabel/.....'

This does not occur with the WD Portable HDD.

*`Good News. I found this link How to make partitions mount at startup? and used Discs to check and edit the mount points. The two drives were slightly different in that one used the UIDD and the other used the label. However I found the "Mount at System Startup box un-ticked" and no entry in "Display Name". The box is now ticked and I have added the relevant display name. In addition I also took ownership in recursive mode. I am now able to copy the files on the SSD in the same way as the those on the HDD and no longer get the error message.`*

Sorry everyone I spoke too soon have found that using the above answer does not solve the original issue. It appears that using Discs to take ownership is not permanent for USB connected external drives and is really just an alternative to using the sudo chown command in terminal which also is not permanent for USB connected external drives. Also,having taken ownership of the SSD Drive, I now find that I have to use the password to unmount.

So my question remains open what do I need to do to ensure that both of the external drives mount with the same ownership and permissions.

In response to waltinator I could not find the files/folders you listed.

Comment: What filesystem do you have on them?

Comment: SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD V2, SanDisk Extreme Pro Portable SSD and SanDisk Professional G-DRIVE SSD use 256-bit AES hardware encryption to protect your data. Is your SSD one of these models?

Comment: It depends on how they're mounted. Look at `mount` or `cat /etc/mtab`. Read `man mount mtab`.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: You can move your 'good news' to a answer (yes, you can answer your own question) and accept the answer (at least after a couple of days). This can be helpful for other users with similar problems.